# why to pass context to a void method in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am following an expert on youtube and making the same as he does..

but i am getting an error in my code ,in Expert Coding he is not passing context to method and eventhought working fine...so...why i am getting an error of context

I know if i pass context it is solved..but want to know why it not showing error to expert code.. whats wrong with my code...

```
void navigateToScreen(Food food)
  {
//showing error to pass context to this method....why?

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
      return ProductDetailScreen(food: food);
    }));
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
       
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              
              
              const Text(
                'Food Menu',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 18,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: foodList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final Food food = foodList[index];
                      return FoodTile(
                        food: food,
                        onTap: ()=>navigateToScreen(food),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean context of .push or of builder? Could you share the link you referenced?

Comment: He would be having this code inside Stateful widget's State class. There context is available.

Comment: Thanks Rahul....you are right...he has used Stateful and i was using stateless...

Answer (score 1):

```
class WidgetExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Food Menu',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 18,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: foodList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final Food food = foodList[index];
                  return FoodTile(
                    food: food,
                    onTap: () => navigateToScreen(food,context),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void navigateToScreen(Food food, BuildContext context) {
//showing error to pass context to this method....why?

  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return ProductDetailScreen(food: food);
      },
    ),
  );
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks but my question was why to pass context......it is solved by rahul...